# TinyMCE 4 addToTop equivalent

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'am trying to migrate a plugin from v3 to v4 of TinyMCE. 
In v3 you could call `ed.onKeyUp.addToTop(function(){})`. 
The equivalent in v4 is`ed.on('keyup', function() {})`.

Now the problem is that my keyup event gets called as last. (There are allready other keyup events registered by other plugin modules.) Is there a way to get my 'keyup' event first in the call hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some hackish way to enable you to do that, but I'll have to instinctively say that you are doing it wrong if you need it. Nevertheless you could unbind the other events, and rebind them again as a possible solution.

Comment: The problem is I have do insert some content into the editor when a user presses the ENTER key. This key event also triggers a carriage return. In TinyMCE v3 i could add my own event at the top of the event queue and stopPropagation of all other events. (https://github.com/Cognistreamer/tinyMCE-mention/blob/master/mention/editor_plugin_src.js#L113).

Comment: preventDefault and stopPrpagation is still available, see the documentation at:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Event